# Does god even exist?

Tags: gods, atheism

I was born to Hindu parents, my father used to bring books on the universe and planets. After reading many books, knowing about evolution, the periodic extinction of species, apes and primary beings I'm no longer sure there is god.

So does god even exist?

Comment: Very well then why are you here what is your purpose of existence, do you come here just by mere probablity that some antimatter particles were less in number than matter particles?? Is it that your forefathers were fool to believe in god after knowing everything about universe? (You should know that the universe's age properites are very well described in hindu scriptures still they believed in some creator (bramhan) you cannot reject them as fools).

Comment: What is your question? So you have read many books and are now an expert on evolution and the universe and you 'know' there is no God. Did you know that evolution was first discovered by the Hindus and is a part of the Hindu religion? Did you know that the Hindu religion teaches that the universe is infinite in space and eternal in duration? As a 'modern scientist' you cannot accept God? Read "Quantum Physics and Ultimate Reality: Mystical Writings of Great Physicists" Editor Michael Green. Also "What is Life?: with 'Mind and Matter'" by Erwin Schroedinger.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - I need this book "Quantum Physics and Ultimate Reality: Mystical Writings of Great Physicists" have you any link for this ?

Comment: I think its a good question atleast for the people who are turning atheist in today's time. People are hardly taught about vedas and puranas these days and with what they learn it is hard to believe in Godly facts. So, i would request people to answer or comment in constructive way instead of crticizing or close votes. The answers to this question can be an eye opener for many people.

Comment: I would like to ad a book in swami Vishwanada's list Tao of physics,also read swami vivekananda how he his master(swami ramkrishna) carved a Yogi out of an Atheist. Also I agree with you Aby..

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, *Hindu Religion* is just a token name given by Iranian Muslims to a vast array of faith believers of present day Indian subcontinent. I don't think the OP is opposing it anyway. It's a good question many atheists have. Even Swami Vivekananda was wandering at many places asking people "Have you see god?" until he met his Guru Ramakrishna.

Comment: @arjun I don't know if stories we hear/read about God are all true or not but certainly there is some Supreme Power. I won't give you extracts from texts as they might have been modified over time to fit a specific belief. See a small example. I read a case where a child spoke a totally different language than his native tongue & identified his previous birth's parents. How would that be possible through science/nature. This is only one case, there are many such cases,google it, This proves that there is some power behind the scenes that is providing a new body to souls after a person's death.

Comment: This is a good question. This all depends how you conceptualise god, and I disagree with most of the answers here. Instead of giving you an answer I will strongly urge you to watch this two videos which will certainly answer your question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU9tSVLDgyQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ftn4zCnheBk

Comment: According to the [Carvaka-Lokayata school](http://www.iep.utm.edu/indmat/) of philosophy, there is no such thing as god/gods/God/soul or after-life.

Answer (score 10):

In Shrimad Bhagwad Gita chapter 7th verse 25

> naham prakashah sarvasya yogamayasamavrutah 
>   moodhoyam nabhijanati loko maamajamavyayam ||
>
> I do not manifest Myself to everyone. I am hidden by My yogamaya potency and thus the foolish cannot recognize Me as eternal and unborn.

Thus GOD exists but everybody does not know him.

In Shrimad Bhagwad Gita chapter 7th verse 26

> Vedaham Samtitani vartamanani charjuna 
>   Bhavishyani cha bhutani mam tu ved ba kaschyana ||
>
> O Arjuna, I know past, present and future. I know all living beings, but they do not know Me.

GOD knows everything but we do not know GOD.

Even in vedas GOD is described as "Neti Neti" means nobody knows GOD who exists eternally.

Answer (score 5):

If you have come across some of the threads on this site, which suggest over the top ages of human and Yugas in thousands of years, which will directly contradict the current form of evolution theory, then that doesn't mean that God itself doesn't exist! :-) 
By staying in such denial, you are unknowingly raising finger on the cultural faiths & researches worth several thousands of years happening across the globe.

A similar question Swami Vivekananda used to ask people, "Have you seen God?". That stopped when his ultimate Guru Shri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa made him realize. But for that, Vivekananda surrendered and kept his mind open. Later he subscribed to the same philosophy [which he used to  ridicule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Vivekananda#With_Ramakrishna). On other hand, Duryodhana did not accept Vishnu's incarnation even after witnessing the event of Vishwaroopam.

A Jeeva-Atma's supreme goal is to get Moksha and that goes through God. It's up to us, which path we want to choose. I would recommend Not be an atheist, who would directly deny God without inquiring more about it. Be an atheist, who doesn't believe God until he has researched it *All*. This will lead you towards *Gyaan marg*.

There is 1 sloka in Gita which tells the importance of a true spiritual Guru and you may want to look for it.

Overall [Bhagavad Gita Chapter 7](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7) is a good chapter to start for the person with lot of atheism.

[BG 7.6](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/6)

> All created beings have their source in these two natures. Of all that
>   is material and all that is spiritual in this world, know for certain
>   that **I am both the origin and the dissolution**.

Especially *beware of* the below:
[BG 7.15](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/15) & [BG 7.25](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/25)

> Those miscreants who are grossly foolish, who are lowest among
>   mankind, whose knowledge is stolen by illusion, and who partake of the
>   (atheistic) nature of demons do not surrender unto Me.
>   ...
>   I am never manifest to the foolish and unintelligent. For them I am
>   covered by My internal potency, and therefore they do not know that I
>   am unborn and infallible.

Even I too believe in the theory of evolution, but then my mind stumbles when I ask myself,
*Who created the first living cell among all? Or Who did the current Big Bang?*
We don't have to let that rebel die inside us, but calm it down to channelize in a right path. e.g. I finally decided to surrender myself to the teachings of Bhagavad Gita, even though I don't have the proofs of it being true. So that I can backtrack my knowledge based on it.

Also, don't rely totally on the evolution theory, it's just < 200 years old and it itself is slowly evolving. There is a whole section of [Sexual Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection) in it, which suggests how male & female choose (read *lust*) their partner based on certain criteria. This might be true, but that's not all.
Here are 2 cents on that!

[BG 16.8](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/16/8)

> They say that this world is unreal, with no foundation, no God in
>   control. They say it is produced of sex desire and has no cause other
>   than lust.

Comment: even though evolution theories are just 200 years old and our scriptures are millions years, why should we follow only old and discard new one. If Science today says- water has 2 H atoms and 1 O atom, though it is new research but cannot be discarded untrue. They argue over each word of a theory put by them. For e.g. though Newton's Law held good for Big particles, for atoms it did not hold good. So Newton's law were not discarded untrue, rather a new and better theory-Quantum Mechanics was developed. So science knowers do not follow orthodox or heretics.How to know if God exists.

Answer (score 2):

How can we know that there is no God if there is no scientific evidence for or against the existence of one? Well, there is actually some historical evidence. The knowledge of the Vedas, however, have shown the words of god to be very accurate to those of science, and Hinduism has many times helped mankind's pursuit of science if not supplemented it. The Puranabharati, an ancient text, also predicts the reincarnations of Vishnu, for which there is historical evidence for. If you look up Adam's Bridge, you can see that there is a lot of consistency between the events of Ramayana and the age of the bridge. These texts also predicted the birth of Gautama Buddha, which we certainly have historical evidence for.

Here is an English version of the Vishnu Purana (Puranabharati) if you are interested:
http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/VishnuPurana.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with God and its interpretations. There is a super power so all the things in the universe still exist. But we gave so many names and so many structures to the God, that may or may not exist. I want to ask a question, you know elephant is a vegetarian. Who is telling them not to take other food.  Suppose from tomorrow elephant becomes non veg, what will be our status?

Another example..lets take a green pea seed in your kitchen. If you want you can keep it inside a bottle for so many days, but if suppose you put it inside water, tomorrow you can see a small pant coming out from it. Who tells that seed to become a plant. In general, there are supernatural powers which are not in our control.

Comment: when some stone is thrown up, who tells it to come down? There is some supernatural force.

Comment: I mean to say that- we just put contradictory and unrelated ideas to proove God. Why do we not take rational arguments? If everything is told by God then why is it so- if God (supernatural force) tells everyone to do everything, then IT must not tell the criminals to do bad, why are then the criminals promoted to do by the supernatural force, God? And are not we following heretics by orthodoxily following old sayings(full of contradiction), and discarding true theories of today as being untrue. Why should we not question our old theories taking account of true theories of today?

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes God exist. If you look at nature you can find it yourself. But it doesn't have any form. Let's look into an elephant. No one tells him that he is vegetarian. The creator of the elephant is a super power who is called as a god.

Comment: Are you really believe in god? if not from where you get "Maya of God?", I don't belive in Maya. You can user your own view to see God. I believe everyone is god and everything is God. But we are not realizing

Comment: God is inside us. We are not realizing that.That why all are doing this. In India, we say "Namaste" when meeting each other. what it really means?

Comment: "Namaste" means I am saluting the god inside you and I am the same what you are. All over activities are closely related to a super power who is the creator of the universe. That creator is a super power called god